# Строка больше 255 символов delphi

Tags: delphi, sql-server, delphi-7

сделал запрос все нормально работает в SQL Server но когда делаю этот запрос в Delphi ругается

код ошибки в Delphi:

```
String literals may have at most 255 elements
```

сам код

```
qry1.SQL.Add('SELECT round(a.FARE,2) as FARE, round(a.takasa,2) as takasa, round(a.foiz_sub,2) as foiz_sub, round(a.dop_zbor_naprav,2) as dop_zbor_naprav, round(a.foiz_AK,2) as foiz_AK, a.*, b.*, c.* FROM TICKET as a, Subagent as b, Agency  as c where a.subagent= b.id and c.id=a.company');
```

ругаться когда вожу таблицу FARE как мне быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ограничение компилятора на длину строки (`shortstring`), которую Вы печатаете прямо в код. Разбейте ее на несколько кусков.

```
var
  str1, str2, str3: string;

...

str1 := 'SELECT round(a.FARE,2) as FARE, round(a.takasa,2) as takasa, round(a.foiz_sub,2) as foiz_sub, ';
str2 := ' round(a.dop_zbor_naprav,2) as dop_zbor_naprav, round(a.foiz_AK,2) as foiz_AK, a.*, b.*, c.* ';
str3 := ' FROM TICKET as a, Subagent as b, Agency  as c where a.subagent= b.id and c.id=a.company';

qry1.SQL.Add(str1 + str2 + str3);
```

или

```
qry1.SQL.Add('SELECT round(a.FARE,2) as FARE, round(a.takasa,2) as takasa, round(a.foiz_sub,2) as foiz_sub,');
qry1.SQL.Add('round(a.dop_zbor_naprav,2) as dop_zbor_naprav, round(a.foiz_AK,2) as foiz_AK, a.*, b.*, c.*');
qry1.SQL.Add('FROM TICKET as a, Subagent as b, Agency  as c where a.subagent= b.id and c.id=a.company');
```

или

```
qry1.SQL.Add(
  'SELECT round(a.FARE,2) as FARE, round(a.takasa,2) as takasa, round(a.foiz_sub,2) as foiz_sub, ' +
  ' round(a.dop_zbor_naprav,2) as dop_zbor_naprav, round(a.foiz_AK,2) as foiz_AK, a.*, b.*, c.* ' + 
  ' FROM TICKET as a, Subagent as b, Agency  as c where a.subagent= b.id and c.id=a.company'
);
```

Comment: можете объяснить свой ответ? какой тип поставить в str?

Comment: `String` а какой же ещё